# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

When I start intellij  I get the following error in every single bean and "org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor";

This is my maven setting file:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>





<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.32</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

That's Run is Error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1335)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1169)
```

Can anyone please team whats going on wrong with the application ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Check that you have spring-aspects in your classpath.
Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>${springVersion}</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aspects', version: springVersion
}
```

Comment: I have `spring-aspects` `5.1.5` in my pom.xml and yet I still get `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue with the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

When I have replaced it by

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.8</version>
</dependency>
```

The problem has totally gone.
I would like to mention that I am using inconsistent versions for aspectj, but the project still works.

```
<!-- AspectJ dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

It can not find **ReflectionWorld** class. Make sure that **[AspectJ Weaver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver)** libraries (aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar) available in your **libs** directory.

Right click on your project -> Open Module Settings -> Dependencies
-> Add (+) -> Library... -> From Maven -> search for `org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.9` and download the dependencies.

Comment: Looks like the OP had `aspectjweaver` version `1.8.9` already specified in his/her pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Add aspectjweaver1.6.8.jar file for
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. In IntellijIDEA, in addition to the need to declare dependencies for an ordinary maven project, you can also check whether your output directory has corresponding dependencies. If not, you can try to put into from the right.  this worked for me[Put into lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q08X5.png)